# Error when I include DirectXTex.h

Tags: c++, directx-11

I get errors when I include DirectXTex.h in my application. I use Visual Studio in Debug 32 bit mode and DirectX11. These is the code:

```
#include "DirectXTex.h"
```

[Here the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMK9H.png)

How can I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indicates you have tried to compile the same source file with both XNAMath (a.k.a xboxmath version 2) and DirectXMath (a.k.a. xboxmath version 3). [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex) uses [DirectXMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath), so you probably have `#include <xnamath.h>` somewhere above `#include "DirectXTex.h"`.

You should update your use of XNAMath to use DirectXMath instead. See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/03/26/introducing-directxmath/) and [MSDN: Code Migration from the XNA Math Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418730.aspx).

> If you are using XNAMath it implies you are also using the legacy DirectX SDK. Make sure you have the paths set up properly (i.e. DXSDK include/lib paths should be listed *after* the standard include/lib paths in the VC++ Directories property page instead of before).
>
> Also you should read [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx), [Where is the DirectX SDK](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/08/05/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/) and [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/) in detail.